# jquery response does not match XMLHttpRequest response

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to replace old, ugly, but still working AJAX with a new, cleaner, more readable, but sadly not working jQuery [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Here's the old code (abbreviated):

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", post_url, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xmlHttp.send(formData);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
    let res = xmlHttp.responseText
    console.log({res})         // res: {"\r\nSuccess!!"} <-- Yes
  }
}
```

which works, but is an eyesore.

Here's the new code:

```
$.post( post_url, data, 
   res => console.log({res})   // res: {"\r\n"} <---------- No!!!!
)
```

which looks nice and works, but doesn't give useful response text...

### ***Why are these responses not the same?***

```
xmlHttp: {"\r\nSuccess!!"}
 $.post: {"\r\n"}
```

Is jQuery is cutting off the response?

Comment: What is the value of `data`?

Comment: If you're trying to send a `FormData` object you need to use `$.ajax()`, not `$.post()`.

Comment: Check the actual response in devtools. Aside from the issue, returning plaintext is very bad practice. If you're refactoring anyway, I'd suggest changing the server side response to something serialised, ef. JSON or XML

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Barmar, I found out that `$.post` can't send [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), and that the server expects that serialized object. I need to use `$.ajax` to send a FormData object.

Here's my final code:

```
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'data', myData);

$.ajax({
  url: post_url,
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: "multipart/form-data",
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    console.log({data});   // {"\r\nSuccess!!"}
  }
})
```